# Option to add new appointment from Calendar pane in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook 2016 (Desktop), within the Mail tab we can add a calendar in the To-Do pane. This shows us the calendar and our list for the next few days etc.

Is there a way to add the option to create a new appointment in the To-Do pane?

At the moment I have enter the calendar screen/view first which is an extra step I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't currently a way to create an appointment from the To Do pane, you can avoid entering the calendar screen by either

- Using the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + A)
- From the mail screen, Select 'New Items' and then 'Appointment'

[image: Seen here]